# Find Duplicate Values From Excel With Linq

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to find duplicate values from some data which coming from Excel:

> **Name | Phone**
>
> Bertug | 5453132727
>
> Mete | 5453132727

How I can find duplicate values from data with LINQ. So far I have:

```
if (cell.Column.Number == myInput.ColumnNumber)
{
    var dublicates = myInput.Sheet.GetRows().GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1); 
}
```

Comment: What means "not working". What results do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: I have dublicates values in xlsx document but I got Count = 0

Comment: Then you should provide some data. Probably you have some sheets with different names where you expect them to be identical, but we can´t guess without seing your data.

Comment: This linq looks like it gets the columns, groups them by name and selects the "key" (whatever that is) and puts any of the duplicate column names in a list. Also, answer @HimBromBeere 's question a bit better.

Comment: From my point it should work, however your data won´t do anything for your question as those are distinct values anyway. You should consider provide some data where it does *not* work. Or does it not work on that data as well?

Comment: With your last (own) edit you deleted the actual solution. When grouping using `x => x` you group by every instance which will call the types `Equals`-method. But I guess you want to group based on a property of that type, so you want `x => x.Name` as you wrote in your first revision.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple solution would be to let Excel work for you and filter the `Range` *in-place* with `AdvancedFilter` method. Here is an simple example of function which will do it.

```
private static IEnumerable<Range> FindDuplicateRows(Range rng)
{
    rng.AdvancedFilter(Action: XlFilterAction.xlFilterInPlace, Unique: true);
    foreach (Range row in rng.Rows)
        if (row.Hidden)
            yield return row;
    rng.Parent.ShowAllData();
}
```

How to call it (the `dupl` contains the duplicate rows of `rng`):

```
Range rng = ((Worksheet)excelWorkSheet).Range["A1:B10"];
IEnumerable<Range> dupl = FindDuplicateRows(rng);

foreach (var r in dupl)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(r.Address);
```